# Making an @import Google Font inline

Tags: html, css, styling, inline-code

I need to make all HTML styling inline. How would I go about adding an @import (Google Font) to the body tag? I have the following code, but it does not work with the @import.

```
<body style="@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market);font-family: 'Chelsea Market', 'Comic Sans', 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;">
```

Comment: You can't add google fonts like that. Put the `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` in your `<head>` element and then add the fonts to the `<body>` like `<body style="font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;">`.

Comment: @Vucko Unfortunately some clients strip out `<head>` and `<link>` tags, so is there a way to entirely have this inline?

Comment: There is also a javascript solution - check the google page for that code.